# SVG animate tag causes undesired put back

Tags: svg, jquery-animate

I am using ANIMATE tag to add some animation to my SVG path. I just set the FROM and TO coordinates, with no loop at all.
It works well but when my path morphs to the final shape it puts back instantly to the beginning "frame" instead of remain in the final shape.

I don't get any error messages, curve just waits, morphs and then goes back to beginning shape.

Comment: You may add `fill="freeze"` to the animation element

Answer (score 0):

I just found out that adding a "fill='freeze'" additional attribute does the job